# how to check all the rows is having value..or not

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

the below one is my table row structure

```
select  c1 from table where  c7 is not null
```

i need c1 value if c7 if any one of the row is having null value it should not 
come may i know who can i do it..
right now i am getting column which is having values but i need  if one time is having null values that entry should not come.

```
c1  c2  c3   c4  c5     c6   c7
31  1   1   BOQ NULL    1   Item5
31  2   1   BOQ NULL    2   Item5
31  3   2   BOQ NULL    3   Itmem7
31  4   3   BOQ NULL    4   Item9
31  5   4   BOQ NULL    5   Item5
31  6   5   BOQ NULL    6   Item5
31  7   6   BOQ NULL    7   NULL
31  8   7   BOQ NULL    8   NULL
31  9   8   BOQ NULL    9   NULL
31  10  9   BOQ NULL    10  NULL
32  1   1   BOQ NULL    1   NULL
32  2   2   BOQ NULL    2   NULL
33  1   0   BOQ NULL    1   NULL
33  2   1   BOQ NULL    3   NULL
```

Comment: Please, format, this is very hard to read!

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/all-subqueries.html ?

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot understand your English here so have no idea what you want.

Comment: @zerkms From the tags I would guess it's SQL Server rather than MySQL but who knows!

Comment: @DavidG The first tag is `mysql` exactly. Not to mention `ALL` is an ANSI SQL function

Comment: @zerkms The tags are in alphabetical order and where do you see `ALL`?

Comment: @DavidG I see it in the link I provided.

Comment: @zerkms I'm guessing this is for SQL Server though as the OP also added SQL Server 2008 tag

Comment: @DavidG good, and I tend to trust tags not my assumptions.

Comment: @zerkms Yet you are assuming this is MySQL? :)

Comment: @DavidG I don't assume, I see the `mysql` tag in the question (not sure if I need to provide a screenshot with a huge red arrow pointing to it)

Comment: @zerkms And I see 2 SQL Server tags.

Comment: @DavidG so? My suggestion is ANSI SQL compatible (even though it refers to a particular vendor documentation). It could even be a link to Oracle documentation and it would change nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select c1
from table
group by c1
having sum(c7 is null) = 0
```

This returns all values of c1 for which there is no c7 value that is null.

For a more generally useful ( all databases) solution, use:

```
having sum(case when c7 is null then 1 end) = 0
```

Or

```
having count(c7) = count(*)
```

Comment: A side note: this query would be (more) ANSI SQL friendly if it didn't use implicit `Bool -> Numeric` cast

Comment: Does this runs on mysql? I tried and it seems I have no results

Comment: @A.D. at first glance - it should run on mysql and return all `c1`'s that don't have `c7 equal null`

Comment: Honestly I would use `COUNT()` since it's more semantic here - we need to get number of elements, not their summary (even if the latter is derived from the former) So simply `COUNT(c7) = 0` or `COUNT(c7 IS NULL) = 0`

Comment: @zerkms FYI `COUNT(C7 IS NULL)  = 0` doesn't work - try it yourself [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c1d38/5)

Comment: @Bohemian oh right, silly me. So yes `COUNT(c7)` then

Comment: @zerkms `COUNT(C7)` on its own  doesn't work either, but I've posted something count-based  that does.

Comment: I didn't say it should be used on its own, I initially addressed the `COUNT` vs `SUM` semantics.

Comment: Shouldn't it be having count(c7) = 0?

Comment: @jarlh no - that would return all c1 that had *all* nulls for c7. `count()` doesn't count nulls.

Comment: @Bohemian, I'm probably lost here, but wasn't the question to find those c1 that have only nulls for c7?

Comment: @jarlh It is hard to tell - English may not be the first language of the OP, but I interpret this *i need c1 value if c7 if any one of the row is having null value it should not come* as meaning don't return c1 values if there's any nulls in any of c1's rows. ie find all c1 with *no* nulls in c7

Answer (score 1):

A `NOT EXISTS` version:

```
select c1
from tablename t1
where not exists (select 1 from tablename t2
                  where t1.c1 = t2.c1 and t2.c7 is not null)
```

Perhaps I misunderstood OP. Above answer returns c1 values who have only NULL for c7.

If the question is to find c1 values with no NULL for c7, change the sub-select's `IS NOT NULL` to `IS NULL`.

If a c1 value should be returned only once even if several occurrences, do `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Comment: `from table t2` --- what is `t2`?